# ¿Por qué no da error en la herencia?

Tags: java, uml

En un ejemplo sin *overrides* sin nada, sólo una herencia simple con el mismo nombre de método, tendría que dar un error pero no me lo da o me equivoco en mi interpretación.

Lo que quiero es esto pero quiero que me genere un error de que no se puede utilizar ese mismo método.

**Coche.java:**

```
public abstract class Coche
{
  public abstract int sampleMethod(int y);
}
```

**Limusina.java:**

```
public class Limusina extends Coche
{
  public Limusina()
  {

  }

  public int sampleMethod(int y)
  {
    return y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Que yo sepa no debe dar error , sino que estas sobreescribriendo el mismo método en la clase hija

Comment: Editaste la pregunta, y borraste el grafico y ahora no se entiende que estas preguntando. por favor arregla la pregunta.

Comment: si, voy a corregir la pregunta @gbianchi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En teoría tu diagrama de clases no debería dar ningún error... 
Si bien en el gráfico invertiste el orden de los métodos y los atributos de la clase, la herencia esta bien planteada.

Lo que tenes son dos clases: una abstracta (FiguraGeometrica) y una concreta (Circulo). Al ser una relación de herencia, la clase Circulo **debe implementar TODOS los MÉTODOS ABSTRACTOS** de la superclase (FiguraGeometrica), en este caso dibujar().

Te quedaria algo asi..

```
public abstract class FiguraGeometrica{
    //atributos generales de una figura geométrica
    //constructor
    public abstract void dibujar(); //para definirlo en las subclases
    }

public class Circulo extends FiguraGeometrica{
    //atributos propios de un circulo
    //constructor
    public void dibujar(){...}; //implementacion propia del circulo
    }
```

Esto te permite aplicar las técnicas de polimorfismo (para crear otras figuras geométricas, como la clase Cuadrado, Triangulo) y binding dinámico (para poder cambiar en tiempo de ejecución la forma de la figura geométrica que quieras utilizar).

Comment: La mejor explicación que te podrian dar aquí la tienes.

Comment: ya se porque esta mál, porque a simple vista esta mal porque si no la sobrescribes, luego ni siquiera implementas el método se convertirá en abstracta.